# How to post a file and form fields in the same request?

Tags: go, http-post

I have the following code which I have tried to use to send a post request where I want to upload a js.map file to bugsnag.

```
...  
body := &bytes.Buffer{}
writer := multipart.NewWriter(body)
part, err := writer.CreateFormFile(filetype, filename)

if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

fmt.Printf("Sending %s to bugsnag", filename)

io.Copy(part, file)
writer.Close()
request, err := http.NewRequest("POST", bugsnagUrl, body)

if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

request.Header.Add("Content-Type", writer.FormDataContentType())

// This is where my problem seems to be, I can't add form values this way because the map is nil
request.Form.Add("apiKey", bugsnagToken)
request.Form.Add("minifiedUrl", fileurl)
request.Form.Add("sourceMap", filename)
request.Form.Add("overwrite", "true")
client := &http.Client{}

response, err := client.Do(request)

if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer response.Body.Close()
```

The above example gives the following error

> panic: assignment to entry in nil map
>
> goroutine 1 [running]: net/url.url.Values.Add(...)

I have been unable to find any examples on how to do this, I used the example on how to upload a file from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51455855/1260548) to get this far.

I seem to be able to post the file but **how can I post a file and also include post form values with my request?**

Comment: Where is api document?

Comment: @KibGzr I don't think it's directly relevant to the question but the Bugsnag documentation for uploading source maps can be found here https://docs.bugsnag.com/api/js-source-map-upload/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add form fields like this

```
writer.WriteField("apiKey", bugsnagToken)
writer.WriteField("minifiedUrl", fileurl)
writer.WriteField("sourceMap", filename)
writer.WriteField("overwrite", "true")
writer.Close()
```