# Sending file between two microservices

Tags: csv, go, microservices

I have two services running as microservices, I get file from user using `Service-1` and then try to `POST` it to `Service-2`, where it will be read and processed.
Here what I had tried.

Service-1:

Form data is taken as:

```
<form  class="formContainer"  id="my_form" action="http://usagemeter:7171/addmanagerstouser">
</form>
```

Controller:

```
    adduserManagersReq := adminservice+"/addmanagerstouser"
    usagerManagersCsv := req.FormValue("user_managers")

    adduserManagersRes, err := http.PostForm(adduserManagersReq, url.Values{"usermanagers": {usagerManagersCsv}})
```

Here csv is passed as `user_manager` in html form.

Service-2:

```
func addManagersToUsers(res http.ResponseWriter,req *http.Request){
    file := req.FormValue("usermanagers")

    fd, err := os.Open(file)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Error opening file")
        fmt.Fprintf(res,"false")
        return
    }
    defer fd.Close()
}
```

Here I get `No such file or directory`.

What am I missing here? Is this possible? or have to use another way to do it?

Comment: You are sending the file *name* from one service to the other. If the two services are running on different hosts, its not surprising the receiving service cannot open the file path. Did you mean to send the file body in the POST?

Comment: @colm.anseo Yes, I want to send the content in that file, and read it from second service.

Comment: Maybe https://www.grpc.io/ is something you want to look at :)

Answer (score 2):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51455855/1218512) shows host to `POST` a file's content:

```
func SendPostRequest (url string, filename string, filetype string) []byte {
    file, err := os.Open(filename)  
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer file.Close()

    body := &bytes.Buffer{}
    writer := multipart.NewWriter(body)
    part, err := writer.CreateFormFile(filetype, filepath.Base(file.Name()))  
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    io.Copy(part, file)
    writer.Close()
    request, err := http.NewRequest("POST", url, body)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    request.Header.Add("Content-Type", writer.FormDataContentType())
    client := &http.Client{}

    response, err := client.Do(request)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer response.Body.Close()

    content, err := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    return content
}
```

And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40699578/1218512) shows how to receive it:

```
func ReceiveFile(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    r.ParseMultipartForm(32 << 20) // limit your max input length!
    var buf bytes.Buffer
    file, header, err := r.FormFile("file")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer file.Close()
    name := strings.Split(header.Filename, ".")
    fmt.Printf("File name %s\n", name[0])
    io.Copy(&buf, file)
    contents := buf.String()
    fmt.Println(contents) // <- process file body here
    buf.Reset()

    return
}
```